# Tratar dataframes y copiar en Excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Tengo dos dudas, quiero realizar un `script` que me compare dos columnas de dos `excels`, `service#1` y `service#2`, si los valores son iguales, copiar el resto de columnas en el `excel2`.

Tengo la comparación hecha, y he conseguido copiar la fecha de un `excel` a otro, el resto de campos no lo he conseguido. Tengo este error que no soy capaz de solucionar:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nombres.py", line 16, in <module>
    dataframe2.at[ind2, 'Tarea']= dataframe1.at[ind1, 'Tarea']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2287, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2815, in _set_value
    engine.set_value(series._values, index, value)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 95, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Mates
```

Este error viene en la linea de `'Cambio'`, `'Baja'` y `'Comentarios'`.
Además no se como guardar solo las columnas modificadas en el `excel2`.

Adjunto todo el código:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe1 = pd.read_excel('Nombres.xlsx', 'Hoja1', usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5))
dataframe2 = pd.read_excel('Nombres2.xlsx', 'Hoja1',usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5))


contador=0


for ind1 in dataframe1.index:
    for ind2 in dataframe2.index:
        if ((dataframe1.at[ind1, 'Nombre']==dataframe2.at[ind2, 'Nombre']) and (dataframe1.at[ind1, 'Apellido']==dataframe2.at[ind2, 'Apellido'])):
            #print dataframe1.at[ind1, 'Service #1']
            contador= contador+1
            dataframe2.at[ind2, 'Fecha']= dataframe1.at[ind1, 'Fecha']
            dataframe2.at[ind2, 'Tarea']= dataframe1.at[ind1, 'Tarea']
            dataframe2.at[ind2, 'NombreTarea']= dataframe1.at[ind1, 'NombreTarea']
            dataframe2.at[ind2, 'Comentario']= dataframe1.at[ind1, 'Comentario']

print dataframe2
```

Adjunto la imagen del `excel`:

(Este es el `excel1`, donde quiero copiar sus datos al `excel` dos, si las columnas 1 y 2 son iguales)

[image]

Y este es el `excel` en donde quiero pegar los datos del anterior, si la columna 1 y 2 son iguales:

[image]

El error lo tengo que solo me deja pegar números, Cuando hay letras error, si en vez de Mates pongo un número si me deja... Seguro que es una tontería.

Comment: ¿En qué línea sucede el `ValueError`? Debe aparecer en el traceback del error completo, ¿podrías indicarlo?

Comment: Hola Dani, primero de todo la operación que planteas es vectorizable en principio por lo puedes conseguir lo mismo de gorma mucho más eficiente que usando dos ciclos for. Por otro lado, el error indica que "CH555133" no se puede convertir a float, lo que es lógico, posiblemente el tipo de tus columnas en el segundo DataFrame no es el correcto. Sería muy bueno que agregaras un ejemplo de ambos archivos (o DataFrames) si es posible (y la salida esperada), esto permitiría reproducir tu problema y dar una respuesta más exacta y rápida.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, he editado la pregunta con la información que me pedís.